# nhibernate not taking mappings from assembly

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle

I'm using fnh and castle nhib facility.

I followed the advice from mike hadlow here: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/integrating-fluent-nhibernate-and.html

here is my FluentNHibernateConfigurationBuilder:

```
public Configuration GetConfiguration(IConfiguration facilityConfiguration)
    {
        var defaultConfigurationBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
        var configuration = defaultConfigurationBuilder.GetConfiguration(facilityConfiguration);

        configuration.AddMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly);

        return configuration;

    }
```

i know the facility is picking it up as i can break inside that method and it steps through.

however, when it's done, non of the mappings are created and i get the following error when i try to save an entity:

No persister for: IsItGd.Model.Entities.User

here is my user class:

```
//simple model of web user
public class User
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

}
```

and here is the mapping:

```
 public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap() {

        Id(x=>x.Id);
        Map(x=>x.FullName);
    }
}
```

i really can't see what the problem is. the strange thing is - is that if i use automapping it picks everything up - but i don't want to use automapping as i can't do certain things in that scenario.

any clues?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been fixed - it was a bug in fnh :(

Answer (score 0):

Are your mapping files located in the same assembly as you domain classes? Otherwise you might want to use UserMap instead of User when specifying the assembly to look in:

```
configuration.AddMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(UserMap).Assembly);
```